# "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]" - Can't Open more than two to four URLs without killing my app

Tags: ios, ios7, openurl, memory-pressure

I am using  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]` to open social media URLs in an app. However, I can't seem to open more than two to four URLs before my app gets killed (app ended unexpectedly). I also notice that when I call the above mentioned method, my memory usage is jumping significantly (I was hoping this would not be the case).

I tried to open the exact same URLs from mail.app, and I can keep opening the URLs without `mail.app` being killed. So definitely something is wrong with my app.

Question 1: Any input on how can I avoid increasing memory usage when I call  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]`.

Question 2: Why is `mail.app` not getting killed, while my app is killed?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to test what causes the memory increase?

Comment: How did you create `url` ? did you use `alloc` ? show some code

Comment: @Leo Natan - I haven't used instruments yet, hoping the simple one line method may have a simpler resolution.

Comment: Calling `openURL:` is pretty straightforward. I assume you do it correctly (not many ways to fail in that). So it could be either a system bug or somewhere else (for example, doing something incorrectly in app delegate or notification handling when becoming inactive or going to background). Instruments will help you.

Comment: @Maulik - The URL is created using "NSURL URLWithString:" method. The string that gets passed to the above method is sanitized using "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding" method.

Comment: @LeoNatan - I don't do anything while going in the background or handle any notifications. Should I? Please guide.

Comment: I am not saying you should. I am saying I don't know what is causing the memory spikes. Instruments will show you which part of the code is doing that.

Comment: @LeoNatan - Good suggestion. I will follow up if no other input comes that helps. Thanks for the note!

Comment: ANSWER: Upon researching another question on stack overflow and following suggestion to remove NSLog (not many of them in my app), things seem to work just fine and my app is not getting killed. I am logging this for any future reference for other readers. If you're getting a message that your app is killed due to MEMORY PRESSURE, try removing NSLog from the app and see if that helps. It helped me! Here is the reference to the other thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061243/how-can-i-address-an-app-that-started-earlier-but-is-terminated-due-to-memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon researching another question on stack overflow and following suggestion to remove NSLog (not many of them in my app), things seem to work just fine and my app is not getting killed. I am logging this for any future reference for other readers. If you're getting a message that your app is killed due to MEMORY PRESSURE, try removing NSLog from the app and see if that helps. It helped me! Here is the reference to the other thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061243/how-can-i-address-an-app-that-started-earlier-but-is-terminated-due-to-memory)