# Terminated due to Memory Pressure with less then 15MB used

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, memory-pressure

I'm facing a strange problem, the app I'm working on it's constantly killed due to Memory Pressure but it's not really using much as you can see in the screenshoot.
So I'm started to look for "other" issues like memory leaks, implicit casting, but I don't really know how to debug this kind of things, so... does anyone know how to get out of this problem ? :)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061243/how-can-i-address-an-app-that-started-earlier-but-is-terminated-due-to-memory

Comment: @iDev it's a different problem, here the memory usage it's little, but thanks :)

Comment: which operation you making through caught this exception

Comment: it's a video editing application, I'm using GPUImage. The crash happen after repeating the saving operation few times (the whole video re-processed and color filters are applied)

Comment: In iOS7 (not 6!) my app is being terminated while the user uses Apple's Camera app. My app is not over using memory and using the Camera inside my app is ok. There is no memory warning delivered to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically `termination due to memory pressure` occurs when the app is suspended by the iOS itself. It happens when your device doesn't have a lot of free memory and it is often a good sign (meaning that this will happen to your app sooner or later when the user closes it).

I would offer you to use Instruments and to find where exactly does your app terminate (if this is the case). The good Instruments tutorial can be found here - http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: I started to handle the memory before arc and I was damn good at it, my app wasn't leaking almost at all... now with arc I feel powerless... by the way, my app is using 10mb...

Comment: @Cesar ARC isn't that dumb at all, it's a fine system but you have to remember a few things when working with CoreGraphics and othe _non-Obj-C_ objects. 10 to 15 MB is absolutely fine. I once had an app that was using up to 150 MB of memory and was running perfectly fine. Try debugging it with Instruments.

Comment: so far I love ARC, but I feel like I have little control :)  
I'm using GPUImage framework that use both OpenGL, CoreGraphics and AVFoundation.

Comment: @Cesar As you've accepted this answer, can you provide some details on exactly how it helped - i.e. what was the actual solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocated for the GPU (e.g. with `glGenFramebuffers`) will not show up in any memory instrumentation I can find, but using too much of this memory will count against you for memory pressure.

In my case, I was leaking by having a code path that missed `glDeleteFramebuffers`.